# Build and deploy IBM MobileFirst Platform 6.3 adapters using Ant Builder

Tags: ant, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying build and deploy adapters from my ant build.xml on to MobileFirst Server,but when i am trying to access the below lines of code in ant.It throws me an error.

Error:
 Could not load definitions from resource
 com/worklight/ant/builders/defaults.properties. It could not be found.

Code:

```
<taskdef resource="com/worklight/ant/builders/defaults.properties">
            <classpath>
                <pathelement
                    location="/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/ant-tools/worklight-ant-builder.jar" />
            </classpath>
        </taskdef>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Deploy application**

I believe your `resource` value is incorrect.

Try changing:

```
<taskdef resource="com/worklight/ant/builders/defaults.properties">
```

To:

```
<taskdef resource="com/worklight/ant/defaults.properties">
```

I have tested with the below script and it worked for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project basedir="." default="target-name">
  <taskdef resource="com/worklight/ant/defaults.properties">
    <classpath>
      <pathelement location="/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/ant-tools/worklight-ant-builder.jar"/>
    </classpath>
  </taskdef>
  <target name="target-name">
    <app-builder
        worklightserverhost="http://my-ip-address:10080"
        applicationFolder="/Users/idanadar/Documents/MobileFirst/Eclipses/workspaces/6300/my-project-name/apps/my-app-name"
        environments="common,iphone"
        nativeProjectPrefix="my-project-name"
        outputFolder="/Users/idanadar/Desktop"/>
  </target>
</project>
```

**Note:** The path to the builder .jar file should be [as stated in the documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/devref/r_ant_tasks_buld_deploy_apps.html?lang=en), however for me at least I received the same error unless using the same path as mentioned in the question.

**Deploy adapter**

Try with the below template (change the required values with your own):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project basedir="." default="target-name">
    <taskdef resource="com/worklight/ant/deployers/antlib.xml">
        <classpath>
            <!-- Change this to the path of the worklight-ant-deployer.jar available in the 
                 server installation folder -->
            <pathelement location="/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/lib/worklight-ant-deployer.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>
    <target name="target-name">
        <!-- if your console is secure, remove the 'secure="false"' attribute -->
        <wladm url="my-ip-address:10080/worklightadmin" secure="false" user="admin" password="admin">
            <deploy-adapter runtime="my-project-name" file="my-adapter-name.adapter"/>
        </wladm>
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: But when i am trying to deploy the adapter it says Error: " Error accessing http://localhost:10080/sample/management-apis/1.0/runtimes/samplebuildAnt/adapters?locale=en_US: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found"  can you help me on this issue as well

Comment: I tried the same code Idan .But still getting this error I tried few    ways to resolve this issue as per  this [link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.getstart.doc/start/c_known_limitations.html) but still facing the same issue..

Comment: Provide your full script.

Comment: Please go through this [github link] (https://gist.github.com/futur/1b70483da2d8c33f1262)for my ant script

Comment: That's quite a large task. Why don't you just create a sample to deploy 1 adapter, get that to work and then modify this huge beast... :)

Comment: I removed all the code except deploy script can you please look into the script(https://gist.github.com/sunnystory/79a06d3e44bfe4081c0f) and help me in solving this issue.

Comment: Is the adapter file in the same folder as the build.xml?

Comment: build.xml is in the root folder of the project and adapters are in the adapters folder of the project ,where as the simple.adapter is in the bin class of the project

Comment: This worked for me when the build.xml and .adapter files were in the same location.

Comment: Ok but i guess the issue is with ipv4 and ipv6 as mentioned in the article above... http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.getstart.doc/start/c_known_limitations.html