# MobileFirst 6.3 adapter deploy through ant throws error

Tags: ant, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

when i am trying to deploy adapter on the local host mobilefirst server through ant it throws 404 notfound error.did any one got this issue .Please help

**My ant build.xml script :**

Build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>


<project basedir="." default="deployadp" name="sample">
    <property environment="env" />
    <property name="ECLIPSE_HOME" value="../../Downloads/eclipse/" />
    <property name="debuglevel" value="source,lines,vars" />
    <property name="target" value="1.7" />
    <property name="source" value="1.7" />

    <taskdef resource="com/worklight/ant/deployers/antlib.xml">
        <classpath>
            <!-- Change this to the path of the worklight-ant-deployer.jar available in the 
                 server installation folder -->
            <pathelement location="/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/lib/worklight-ant-deployer.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>


    <target name="deployadp" >
            <echo message=" deploy adapter start" />
        <wladm url="http://localhost:10080/sample" secure="false" user="admin"
            password="admin">
            <deploy-adapter runtime="sample"
                file="/Users/rahulc/workspace2/sample/bin/sample2.adapter" />
        </wladm>
            <echo message="deploy  adapter end" />
    </target>


</project>
```

**Error I am getting after build:**

```
Buildfile: /Users/rahulc/workspace2/sample/build.xml

deployadp:
     [echo]  deploy adapter start
    [wladm] Error accessing http://localhost:10080/sample/management-apis/1.0/runtimes/sample/adapters?locale=en_US: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

BUILD FAILED
/Users/rahulc/workspace2/sample/build.xml:19: com.ibm.worklight.admin.restclient.RESTException: Error accessing http://localhost:10080/sample/management-apis/1.0/runtimes/sample/adapters?locale=en_US: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.restclient.RESTClient.getResponse(RESTClient.java:1189)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.restclient.RESTClient.getPOSTResponse(RESTClient.java:1326)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.restclient.RESTClient.getPOSTFileResponse(RESTClient.java:1348)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.commands.DeployAdapter.getResponse(DeployAdapter.java:41)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.restclient.ActionClient.execute(ActionClient.java:85)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.ant.types.AbstractActionElement.executeCommand(AbstractActionElement.java:76)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.ant.types.ActionElement.executeCommands(ActionElement.java:43)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.ant.WladmTask.executeCommands(WladmTask.java:533)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.ant.WladmTask.execute(WladmTask.java:382)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
```

I looked into Ibm website and found few work arounds like this:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21680420

But this dint help me as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Build and deploy IBM MobileFirst Platform 6.3 adapters using Ant Builder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27474639/build-and-deploy-ibm-mobilefirst-platform-6-3-adapters-using-ant-builder)

Comment: I was mentioning the whole error report here Idan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This section looks wrong to me:

```
<target name="deployadp" >
            <echo message=" deploy adapter start" />
        <wladm url="http://localhost:10080/sample" secure="false" user="admin"
            password="admin">
            <deploy-adapter runtime="sample"
                file="/Users/rahulc/workspace2/sample/bin/sample2.adapter" />
        </wladm>
            <echo message="deploy  adapter end" />
    </target>
```

You are pointing to "sample" in the `wladm` element. You should point to "worklightadmin" instead.

Your runtime (projet name) "sample", is **not** (and should not be) the same as the wladm.

```
<wladm url="http://localhost:10080/sample" secure="false" user="admin" password="admin">
```

Comment: Even tried without sample            <wladm url="http://localhost:10080/" secure="false" user="admin" password="admin"> its throughing same error

Answer (score 0):

The url that i have entered was wrong .The below worked for me

```
<wladm url="http://localhost:10080/worklightadmin" secure="false" user="admin" password="admin">
```

Thanks for the help Idan.you were so helpful.